# How to pivot the following pandas table in the following way using a a chaining method?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I need this to look like this:

```
team,points
Brazil,3
Scotland,0
Morocco,1
Norway,1
```

The table is in the dataframe and I've been trying with `.stack()`, `.unstack()`, and others and I can't seem to get it right. **I really want to do it with a chaining method, like `.something()`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `pd.wide_to_long`. However, you need to pre-process the dataframe column names to appropriate names to use `pd.wide_to_long`

```
df.columns = ['|'.join([y, x]) for x, y in df.columns.str.split('_', n=1)]
df_out = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), ['team', 'team_points'], 'index', 'name', 
                         sep='|', suffix='\w+').reset_index(drop=True)

Out[200]:
       team  team_points
0    Brazil            3
1   Morocco            1
2  Scotland            0
3    Norway            1
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Andy L. one liner. Saw it after I made this attempt

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'home_team':['Brazil', 'Morocco'], 'away_team':['Scotland','Norway'], 'homepoint':[3,1],'awaypoint':[0,1]})
```

[Melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the dataframe

```
df2=pd.melt(df,  id_vars=['home_team','away_team'],value_vars=['homepoint','awaypoint'], value_name='points').drop(columns=['variable'])
```

Slice dataframe and concat

```
df3=df2.iloc[:,1:].rename(columns={'away_team':'team'})
df4=df2.iloc[:,:1:].rename(columns={'home_team':'team'})
pd.concat([df3,df4]).dropna()
```